# Command injection attack: tempered input value with &&

Tags: java, unix, command

Controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/output/")
@ResponseBody
public Object command_injected(@RequestParam String command) {
    Map<String, String> response_data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {
        String output = "";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 3 " + command) ;

        String line = "";
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader errorStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line + "<br/>";
        }
        inputStream.close();
        while ((line = errorStream.readLine()) != null) {
            output += line + "<br/>";
        }
        errorStream.close();
        p.waitFor();

        response_data.put("status", "success");
        response_data.put("msg", output);
        return response_data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response_data.put("status", "error");
        response_data.put("msg", "No output found");
        return response_data;
    }
}
```

example input (Linux):

```
 8.8.8.8 && ls && whoami
```

To show a command injection attack, I want to temper my input using &&. If I enter only IP address, this thing works. If I enter the above example, things are not ok and giving me the following:

```
ping: whoami: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Please help!!